# Node.js tests failing on toLocaleString

Tags: node.js, localization, internationalization, react-testing-library

Good morning,

I have a native js Date object, that I render in to my component with `.toLocaleString("en-GB")`

In the browser I get `29/12/2021, 09:00:00`; however when I run a unit test with react-testing-library and jest:

```
expect(screen.getByText("29/12/2021, 09:00:00")).toBeInTheDocument();
```

The assertion fails because the locale date has been output as `2021-12-29T09:00:00.000Z`

I have found the following ticket, https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8500 which says I need to  build it with `--with-intl=full-icu` or `--with-intl=system-icu`, and I have also referred to the documentation at https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/intl.html#.

I have tried adding this to my package.json under scripts as :

```
"start": "react-scripts start --with-intl=full-icu",
"build": "react-scripts build --with-intl=full-icu",
"test": "react-scripts test --with-intl=full-icu"
```

But when I do `npm run test` while I see it on the executed command it doesn't make a difference.

I am using node v10.16.0.

How can I get node to honour .toLocaleString("en-GB") when running tests, please?

Thank you.

Comment: You should refer: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-intl/

Comment: Thank you Dhruv, I will check it out.